# ¿Cómo solucionar el problema de CORS en .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

```
using API_BSale.Entities;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace API_BSale.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("Permisos")]
    public class C_product : ControllerBase
    {
    private string connectionDB = @"Cadena de conexion";

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        IEnumerable<Entities.product> products;
        using (var db = new MySqlConnection(connectionDB))
        {
            var query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url_image, p.price, p.discount, p.category FROM product AS p";
            products = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, commandTimeout: 300);
        }
        return Ok(products);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetProductbyParameter(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<Entities.product> products;
        using (var db = new MySqlConnection(connectionDB))
        {
            var query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url_image, p.price, p.discount, p.category FROM product AS p WHERE p.category = " + id;
            products = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, commandTimeout: 300);
        }
        return Ok(products);
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public IActionResult GetProductbyName(String name)
    {
        IEnumerable<Entities.product> product;
        using (var db = new MySqlConnection(connectionDB))
        {
            var query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url_image, p.price, p.discount, p.category FROM product AS p WHERE p.name LIKE '%" + name + "%'";
            product = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, commandTimeout: 300);
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
}}
```

Estoy haciendo una pequeña práctica, mi problema es que si agrego este método *"GetProductbyName"* en la página web que estoy haciendo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://localhost:7237/api/C_product/2 (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 500.

Pero si quito el método antes mencionado (*"GetProductbyName"*) deja de aparecer.
¿Cómo podría poner el método *"GetProductbyName"* sin que me ocasione problemas del CORS?

En la clase *Program.cs* agregué estas líneas de código, se supone que con esto ya no debería mostrarme ese error:

```
//Agregada
var MyAllowSpecificationOrigins = "Permisos";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Agregada
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificationOrigins,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            
         policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                        });
 });

  // Add services to the container.

  builder.Services.AddControllers();
  // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at 
  https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
  builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

  var app = builder.Build();

  // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
      app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  //Agregada
  app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificationOrigins);

  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.MapControllers();

  app.Run();
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta e incluye lo que tienes en el `Startup.cs` y `Program.cs`

Comment: Ya. Es .Net6 por lo que la clase Startup.cs ya no existe

Comment: Como ese dato no ha sido especificado en la versión original de la pregunta, era necesario aclarar. ¿Puedes hacer alguna petición a cualquier endpoint y te da el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Si, las primeras 2 consultas si me las hace sin que aparezca el error, pero obviamente entgo que quitar el metodo que me causa conflicto

Comment: intenta colocar esto: `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]` y en el otro que te da conflicto `[HttpGet("{name:string}")]` Está muy raro el tema porque en teoría y según lo que dices, tienes todo bien definido.

Comment: Me genera error y ya no me muestra los links de los metodos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140525/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-macx).

Comment: Yo creo que no hay ningún problema con el CORS, te está dando un error 500 el controlador por algo que tienes en ese método y al no funcionar el verbo OPTIONS te da error de CORS. En tú mensaje de error pone "Código de estado: 500."

Comment: Lo solucione poniedo esta parte asi: "[HttpGet("[action]/{name}")]" aunque exactamente no se como funciona